# How to safely update my state when I have to traverse and lookup/remove items in my state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I need to modify my state and I am unsure how to do it correctly.

My account property in my state looks something like this:

```
{     
 "account":{  
    "id":7,    
    "categories":[  
       {  
          "id":7,          
          "products":[  
             {                  
                "productId":54                
             }
          ]
       },
       {  
          "id":9,          
          "products":[  
             {                  
                "productId":89                
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
}
```

My action dispatches the following:

```
dispatch({
  type: Constants.MOVE_PRODUCT,
  productId: 54,
  sourceCategoryId: 7,
  targetCategoryId: 9
});
```

Now my reducer skeleton is:

```
const initialState = {
  account: null,
};


const accounts = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.MOVE_PRODUCT:
      /*
      action.productId
      action.sourceCategoryId
      action.targetCategoryId
      */

      const sourceCategoryIndex = state.account.categories.findIndex((category) => { return category.id === action.sourceCategoryId; });
      const sourceCategory = state.account.categories[sourceCategoryIndex];

      const targetCategoryIndex = state.account.categories.findIndex((category) => { return category.id === action.targetCategoryId; });
      const targetCategory = state.account.categories[targetCategoryIndex];

    // ??

      return {...state};
  }
}

export default accounts;
```

I am confused, if I update the state directly inside of the switch block, is that wrong?

Does it have to be a one-liner update that does the mutation in-place or as long as I do it in the switch block it is fine?

**Update**

*From the action, I need to remove the productId from the sourceCategoryId and add it to the targetCategoryId inside of the account state object.*

Comment: You shouldn't update the state directly or mutate it. Unless you do those you can do anything in your case block. How do you want to update your state? I can't understand by looking at your action, maybe it's not clear for me. But, if you give some more details it will be useful.

Comment: Move product but what will happen the moved one (source)? Delete the product or something else?

Comment: @devserkan yes, remove from sourceCategoryId and add to targetCategoryId.

Comment: consider normalizing your state to look more like a relational db, it would remove the need to traverse the state tree (since it's now flat)

Comment: Yeah, as its current shape it is very difficult to update it. I'm on it and I will provide a solution but it is very ugly :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should not be doing `state.foo = 'bar'` in your reducer. From the [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions):

> We don't mutate the state. We create a copy with `Object.assign()`. `Object.assign(state, { visibilityFilter: action.filter })` is also wrong: it will mutate the first argument. You must supply an empty object as the first parameter. You can also enable the object spread operator proposal to write `{ ...state, ...newState }` instead.

So your reducer could look like

```
function accountsReducer (state = initialState, { sourceCategoryId, productId }) {
  const targetProduct = state.categories
    .find(({ id }) => id === sourceCategoryId)
    .products
    .find(({ id }) => id === productId);

  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.MOVE_PRODUCT:
      return {
        ...state,
        categories: state.categories.reduce((acc, cat) => {
          return cat.id !== sourceCategoryId
            ? {
                ...acc,
                cat: { ...cat, products: cat.products.filter(({ id }) => id !== productId) }
              }
            : {
                ...acc,
                cat: { ...cat, products: [...cat.products, targetProduct] }
              }
        }, {});
      };
  }
}
```

But this a pain...you should try to [normalize your data](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/normalizingstateshape) into a flat array.

Comment: thanks for that normalize link, going to look into that.

Comment: btw, how would I use this reducer in my current switch statement?

Comment: initial state doesn't have categories, it has account.  so we need another level right?

Comment: in the ``` return { ...state, state.account.categories: ``` part? but that won't return an account.

Comment: Post the code where you are calling `createStore`. IMO you should be instantiating an empty `account.categories` array in your `initialState` so that in your reducer you don't have to check that the array exists.

Comment: My initial store code is in my question, account is set as null.

Answer (score 0):

```
// first, let's clean up the action a bit
// type and "payload". I like the data wrapped up in a bundle with a nice
// bow on it. ;) If you don't like this, just adjust the code below. 
dispatch({
  type: Constants.MOVE_PRODUCT,
  payload: { 
      product: { productId: 54 }
      sourceCategoryId: 7,
      targetCategoryId: 9
  }
});

// destructure to get our id and categories from state
const { id, categories } = state

// map the old categories to a new array
const adjustedCategories = categories.map(cat => {
    // destructure from our payload
    const { product, sourceCategoryId, targetCategoryId } = action.payload

    // if the category is the "moving from" category, filter out the product
    if (cat.id === sourceCategoryId) {
        return { id: cat.id, products: [...cat.products.filter(p => p.productId !== product.productId)
    }

    // if the category is our "moving to" category, use the spread operator and add the product to the new array
    if (cat.id === targetCategoryId) {
        return { id: cat.id, products: [...cat.products, product] }
    }
)

// construct our new state
return { id, categories: adjustedCategories }
```

This solution keeps the function pure and should give you what you want. It's not tested, so may not be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the following approach:

```
const accounts = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.MOVE_PRODUCT:

      // Extract action parameters
      const { productId, sourceCategoryId, targetCategoryId } = action

      // Manually "deep clone" account state
      const account = {
        id : state.account.id,
        categories : state.account.categories.map(category => ({          
          id : category.id,
          products : category.products.map(product => ({ productId : product.productId })
        }))
      }

      // Extract source and target categories
      const sourceCategory = account.categories.find(category => category.id === sourceCategoryId);
      const targetCategory = account.categories.find(category => category.id === targetCategoryId);

      if(sourceCategory && targetCategory) {

        // Find product index
        const index = sourceCategory.products.findIndex(product => (product.productId === action.productId))
        if(index !== -1) {

          const product = sourceCategory.products[index]

          // Remove product from source category
          sourceCategory.products.splice(index, 1) 

          // Add product to target category
          targetCategory.products.splice(index, 0, product) 
        }
      }

      return { account };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ugly solution :)

```
const accounts = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.MOVE_PRODUCT:
      const sourceCategoryIndex = state.account.categories.findIndex(
        el => el.id === action.sourceCategoryId
      );

      const targetCategoryIndex = state.account.categories.findIndex(
        el => el.id === action.targetCategoryId
      );

      const sourceCategory = state.account.categories.find(
        el => el.id === action.sourceCategoryId
      );

      const targetCategory = state.account.categories.find(
        el => el.id === action.targetCategoryId
      );

      const itemToMove = sourceCategory.products.find(
        el => el.productId === action.productId
      );

      const newSourceCategory = {
        ...sourceCategory,
        products: sourceCategory.products.filter(
          el => el.productId !== action.productId
        )
      };

      const newTargetCategory = {
        ...targetCategory,
        products: [...targetCategory.products, itemToMove]
      };

      const newCategories = Object.assign([], state.account.categories, {
        [sourceCategoryIndex]: newSourceCategory,
        [targetCategoryIndex]: newTargetCategory
      });

      return { ...state, account: { ...state.account, categories: newCategories } };
  }
};
```

Phew :) As a learner it's quite good for me :) But, I like @Daniel Lizik's approach, using `reduce`.

Here is the working example:

```js
const action = {
  productId: 54,
  sourceCategoryId: 7,
  targetCategoryId: 9,
}

const state = {     
 "account":{  
    "id":7,    
    "categories":[  
       {  
          "id":7,          
          "products":[  
             {                  
                "productId":54,             
             },
             {                  
                "productId":67,             
             },
          ]
       },
       {  
          "id":9,          
          "products":[  
             {                  
                "productId":89,               
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
};

const sourceCategoryIndex = state.account.categories.findIndex( el => el.id === action.sourceCategoryId );
const targetCategoryIndex = state.account.categories.findIndex( el => el.id === action.targetCategoryId );

const sourceCategory = state.account.categories.find( el => el.id === action.sourceCategoryId );
const targetCategory = state.account.categories.find( el => el.id === action.targetCategoryId );

const itemToMove = sourceCategory.products.find( el => el.productId === action.productId );

const newSourceCategory = {...sourceCategory, products: sourceCategory.products.filter( el => el.productId !== action.productId ) };

const newTargetCategory = { ...targetCategory, products: [ ...targetCategory.products, itemToMove ] };

const newCategories = Object.assign([], state.account.categories, {             [sourceCategoryIndex]: newSourceCategory,
   [targetCategoryIndex]: newTargetCategory }
);

const newState = { ...state, account: { ...state.account, categories: newCategories } };

console.log( newState );
```